# Unable to send emails to Sharedmailbox using SharePoint workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

Have you guys ever faced an issue when you try to add a online Shared mailbox to SharePoint workflow? I am not sure even if this feature is available or not? Can anyone know if Microsoft is allowing SharePoint online workflow to send email to "Shared Mailbox"?

Note: All our online Shared mailboxes are in block stage. Is this because of that they not showing up while adding them to "SharePoint workflow" . Is there any alternative to add them to workflow without even unblocking them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the shared mailbox isn't working when you choose it from the global address list; instead you can store the shared mailbox email address as a variable within the workflow, then have the email sent to that variable.
[image: Screenshots to support answer]

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do you any example info on this. If yes, can you please share it here?

Comment: Added screenshots as example to support

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cannot enumerate the mailbox as a SharePoint user. To get around this, you can add the mailbox to the members group of a site and magically the workflow will send email to that address.

Or alternatively, you can trigger SP Workflow 2010 from SP WF 2013 to send the email to Shared Mail.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will add shared mailbox in a group and will give a quick try if it works or not